# Insert value in array after every index using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have fetch value from database and returning its array in json format. This is my code to get values. First array is working fine. But i need to add static array after every index in array. This is my code

```
$value = $this->TestModel->get_user_details($userIds);
```

this function returns array in json format e.g.

```
[
        {
            "user_id": "1",
            "name": "test 1",
            
        },
        {
            "user_id": "2",
            "name": "test 2",
        },
        {
            "user_id": "3",
            "name": "test 3",
        },
     ]
```

now i need to add below static json array with every item of array. This is e.g

```
 $test1= array("student_list"=> array(array("stu_id"=>1, "name"=> "abc") , array("stu_id"=>2, "name"=> "xyz")),
           "class"=> "12th",
           "average_score"=>"5",
        "results"=>array(array("result_date"=>"2012-12-13","city"=>"city 1"),array("result_date"=>"2015-10-13","city"=>"city 2")));
```

I have tried it with array_push and array_merge but it add this at the end end of array.

I need this Response

```
[
        {
            "user_id": "1",
            "name": "test 1",
            "student_list": [
                {
                    "stu_id": 1,
                    "name": "abc",
                   
                },
                {
                    "stu_id": 2,
                    "name": "xyz",
                   
                }
            ],
            "class": "12th",
            "average_score": "5",
            "results": [
                {
                    "result_date": "2012-12-13",
                    "city": "City 1",
                   
                   
                },
                {
                    
                    "result_date": "2012-10-13",
                    "city": "City 2",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "user_id": "2",
            "name": "test 2",
            "student_list": [
                {
                    "stu_id": 3,
                    "name": "asd",
                   
                },
                {
                    "stu_id": 4,
                    "name": "ghj",
                   
                }
            ],
            "class": "10th",
            "average_score": "5",
            "results": [
                {
                    "result_date": "2011-12-13",
                    "city": "City 3",
                   
                   
                },
                {
                    
                    "result_date": "2011-10-13",
                    "city": "City 4",
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

Comment: kindly add the sample output you want after adding the static JSON

Comment: Why does student_list in your desired output vary between students? That doesn't seem consistent with "now i need to add below static json array with every item of array"

Comment: The array you want to push is definitely not a "static array". Too many properties you're asking but no one of them had been explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add `$test1` to to every element you your array you should merge each element, like so:

```php
$value = $this->TestModel->get_user_details($userIds);

$test1 = array(
    "student_list" => array(array("stu_id" => 1, "name" => "abc"), array("stu_id" => 2, "name" => "xyz")),
    "class" => "12th",
    "average_score" => "5",
    "results" => array(array("result_date" => "2012-12-13", "city" => "city 1"), array("result_date" => "2015-10-13", "city" => "city 2"))
);

$decoded = json_decode($value, true);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($decoded); $i++) {
    $decoded[$i] = array_merge($decoded[$i], $test1);
}

$value = json_encode($decoded);
```